# O que significa a palavra "of" em RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

O que significa a palavra "of" em RxJS ?
Exemplo:

```
const source = of('World').pipe(
  map(x => `Hello ${x}!`)
);
```

Comment: Converte os argumentos em uma sequência observável. Da documentação. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada na documentação: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html

Comment: Se procurar no [google search for: `rxjs of`](https://www.google.com/search?q=rxjs+of&oq=rxjs+of&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60l3.4203j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) virá um bom aporte de documentação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como @LINQ comentou, o operador de criação `of` converte os argumentos em uma sequência observável:

```
// RxJS v6+
import { of } from 'rxjs';
//emits any number of provided values in sequence
const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
//output: 1,2,3,4,5
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Resultado no console:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Link para documentação: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of

O link abaixo mostra uma tabela para dar uma ideia de qual operador de criação deve ser utilizado de acordo com o cenário:

https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/which_operator_do_i_use/creation_operators.html